# PHP Echo does not include line spacing

Tags: php, string, echo, line, spacing

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="10" type="text" name="inputMessage" value="" </textarea> </textarea> <br>
```

```
$message = $_POST['inputMessage'];
echo $message;
```

When the inputMessage is:
   lorem ipsum dolor
   lorem ipsum dolor

It prints it without line spacing. like 'lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolor'

Comment: I'd bet that if you look at the actual source of the message, the linebreaks are there. It's just that HTML ignores them. You have to  use one of the methods mentioned in the actual answers here to make them display in the rendered HTML.

Comment: If I check that same message from my MySQL database it has linebreaks there. When I post it it doesn't have them anymore.  So you're right

Answer (score 4):

```
$message = nl2br($_POST['inputMessage']);
echo $message;
```

Should do the trick, [nl2br documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: This adds <br>, not \r

Comment: <br> or <br /> are both HTML tags for a linebreak.

Comment: <br> does same as double hitting enter in notepad

Comment: Which is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the answer, but I assume he deleted it since it doesn't exist anymore after I refreshed the page.

The solution was this:

```
echo nl2br($message);
```

Other solutions may produce double-line-spacing even if there just one.